# Failure in setting Content Security Policy with "setHeader" in my server code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I'm trying to set the 'Content-Security-Policy' of my server by setting the header as shown here:

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type');
res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', "script-src 'self'");
return next();
})
```

because it is showing the following error :
*it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'"* ,
**But** it is still showing this error and Content-Security-Policy is still to be default-src 'none' after deploying it with heroku **heroku open** .

So my question: Why is  Content Security Policy not changed here ?
Is there another method to set the CSP ?

please explain your answer well .